# Moving Roaming folder

Tags: cleaning, disk-cleanup, appdata

My `C:` is always full and the main reason is because of the `Roaming` folder, I see people on the Internet move it to another drive to save space. Is it really safe to do this? How to move it, I always get access denied? If I successfully moved it, will the new app's data store in the old or the new location?

Comment: “Is it really safe to do this?” - No

Comment: You could spend time identifying the folder(s) inside the Roaming directory that are taking up space. There are folders that CAN be moved and work pretty well, but the AppData folders are not among these.

Comment: Unless your C: partition is at least 50 GB (office system) or 100 GB (software development) it is too small. How big is it?

Comment: @DanielB My C: is 59.9 GB and after I delete all chrome cache, I got 8GB free left